# angular project throw error "this.reflectionCapabilities.guards is not a function"

Tags: angular

I have an angular project with `package.json` like this:

[image]

When I run `npm start`, it doesn't throw error. But when I open the browser, it throws error in console like this:

[image]

Comment: do you have any router guards in place?

Comment: Yes, I have a router guards in my `app.routing.ts`

Comment: I have this error, and don't have any router guards in place, I doubt this has anything to do with that. This happened after I had to npm install again because of node-sass, I'm guessing this is some kind of version mismatch somewhere in the angular dependencies :(

Comment: Did anyone get any solution for this? I am also facing the same issue.